# Find all positive integer $a,b,c$ that $a^3+b^3+c^3$ can be divided by $a^2b,b^2c,c^2a$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations, cubics

> Find all triplets of positive integers $(a,b,c)$ for which
>   $$a^3+b^3+c^3$$ 
>   is divisible by $a^2b$, $b^2c$ and $c^2a$.

I just found that $a=b=c$ satisfies the problem.  Are there any other possible answers?

How to find all possible answers?

Comment: $(a,b,c)=(k,k,-k)$

Comment: @KentaS $k$ and $-k$ cannot both be positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive integers for which $a^3+b^3+c^3$ is divisible by $a^2b$, $b^2c$ and $c^2a$. Then $\gcd(a,b)^3$ divides $a^2b$, $a^3$ and $b^3$, and hence also
$$(a^3+b^3+c^3)-a^3-b^3=c^3,$$
which shows that $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $c$, so $\gcd(a,b,c)=\gcd(a,b)$. By symmetry
$$\gcd(a,b,c)=\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)=\gcd(b,c),$$
and dividing $a$, $b$ and $c$ by this common factor yields another solution, so we may assume without loss of generality that $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$. Then it follows that $a^3+b^3+c^3$ is divisible by
$$\gcd(a^2b,b^2c,c^2a)=a^2b^2c^2.$$
Also without loss of generality $a\leq b\leq c$, and so
$$a^2b^2c^2\leq a^3+b^3+c^3\leq3c^3,$$
which shows that $a^2b^2\leq3c$. In particular, because $c^2$ divides $a^3+b^3+c^3$ we also have
$$c^2\leq a^3+b^3\leq2b^3,$$
and putting this together with $b^2\leq a^2b^2\leq3c$ we find that
$$c^4\leq4b^6\leq108c^3,$$
and hence that $c\leq108$. From here it is easy to verify that $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,2,3)$ are the only valid triplets (up to permutation and scaling) though without the help of a computer this may take some time.

---

To verify this manually, note that from $a^2b^2\leq3c$ and $a\leq b$ and $c\leq108$ we get
$$b\leq\frac{\sqrt{3c}}{a}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad a\leq\sqrt[4]{3c}<5.$$

For $a=4$ we have $b\leq\tfrac{\sqrt{3c}}{a}<5$ and so from $a\leq b$ we get $b=4$. This contradicts $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

For $a=3$ we have $b\leq\frac{\sqrt{3c}}{a}\leq6$. From $\gcd(a,b)=1$ it follows that $b\in\{4,5\}$ and so either
$$a^3+b^3=7\times13\qquad\text{ or }\qquad a^3+b^3=2^3\times19.$$
Because $c^2$ divides $a^3+b^3$ and $c\geq b$ we again reach a contradiction.

For $a=2$ we have $b\leq\frac{\sqrt{3c}}{a}\leq9$ . Then $b\in\{3,5,7,9\}$ and so the the factorizations
$$2^3+3^3=3\times7\qquad 2^3+5^3=7\times19\qquad 2^3+7^3=3^3\times13\qquad 2^3+9^3=11\times67,$$
again yield a contradiction with the facts that $c\geq b$ and $c^2$ divides $a^3+b^3$.

For $a=1$ we have $b\leq\frac{\sqrt{3c}}{a}\leq18$. Clearly $(a,b,c)=1$ is a solution, and for any other solution we have $c\geq2$ and $c>b$. We know that $c^2$ divides
$$a^3+b^3=1+b^3=(1+b)(b^2-b+1),$$
and computing the factorizations for all $b\leq18$ shows that this product is divisible by a square **greater than $b^2$** only if $b=2$, and then $c=3$.

Comment: I think its $c^4<4b^6<108c^3$

Comment: @Joshua You are absolutely right, I have corrected it. This increases the finite number of triplets to check by quite a bit, but it is still quickly done with the help of a computer.

Comment: Btw nice work dude

Comment: @Joshua Thank you. I will update my answer shortly with an effective method to check these triplets reasonably quickly without the help of a computer.

Comment: @Joshua Updated the answer, now I'm satisfied too ;)

Comment: Well done dude.

Answer (score 1):

There are other solutions.

E.g. $(a, b, c) = (k, 2k, 3k), (k, 3k, 2k)$ (which are different up to symmetry).